# JIRA: Allow user to edit his projects schemes

Tags: administration, jira, jira-agile

I want to allow a JIRA project administrator to configure his own issue-type schemes, screen schemes, workflows etc.

If the user is anything less than jira-administrator, all those objects are read only.

Is it possible to extend these permissions to a project administrator restricted to the schemes attached to his project or can I explicitely allow only certain schemes to be edited by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to play with security groups lately for different clients using JIRA and from my understanding, the configuration of a project's templates (scheme, screens,etc..) requires a group tagged with [[ADMIN]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBLk8.png)

The utmost group you can give a regular user is "Group (jira-administrators)" which has "Administer Projects" permission at the project level, which lets them add components,versions, and similar things but nothing close to what you want to achieve.

Maybe vote on this issue : https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-3156

UPDATE July 2017 --------------------

Atlassian seems to have updated some of these settings with the release of jira 7.4.X for more info please read the full patch notes : https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjira/jira-platform-releases/jira-7-4-x-platform-release-notes